# High CPU and energy usage in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, performance, cpu, temperature

Energy impact of Safari is extremely high on my Macbook Air Mid 2013 El Captian 10.11.2. It lead to high usage of CPU (Temperature ~65.0°C) and the CPU fan is running in full speed (6500.0 RPM) constantly.

I have tried so far:

1. Clear all Safari cached
2. Restart laptop
3. Remove/disable all extensions
4. Uninstall all the software that might possibly affecting e.g. Anti-Virus

The issue is only happening in Safari. Chrome and Firefox are both OK.

Thanks for helping in advance!

CPU:
[image: CPU]

Energy Impact 1:
[image: Energy Impact 1]

Energy Impact 2:
[image: Energy Impact 2]

CPU Temperature and Fan Speed:
[image: CPU Temperature and Fan Speed]

Network Activity:
[image: Network Activity]

Comment: 65 degrees is not really dangerous for the mac, max temp is around 100 degrees ;) It seems that your are downloading something ?

Comment: The weird thing is I am not doing anything with Safari. Just randomly opened a few tabs like Google and Facebook and leave it there. Also it is not making any sense to me that an idle Safari can generate 65+ degrees.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably a little late but I hope it helps someone else.

**I found the reason Safari was using so much CPU was due to faulty permissions. It was stuck in a loop trying to access a file it couldn't.**

To see if this might be an issue for you run:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --verify --standard-pkgs /
```

And see if there are any files wile damaged permissions.
For me it was:

```
Permissions differ on "Library/Java", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are drwxrwxr-x .
User differs on "private/var/db/displaypolicyd", should be 0, user is 244.
Group differs on "private/var/db/displaypolicyd", should be 0, group is 244.
```

So it is a good chance Java permissions are the culprit. To fix run:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /
```

And then restart Safari. For me this immediately dropped CPU use from 150% to 14%.

One should note if you have 100s of faulty permissions, it could be an early sign of disk failure. As always, keep backups.

I hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: Seems `repair_packages` is not available in macSierra. Not found here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to delete the caches ?

```
Enable 'Develop' mode in Safari (Safari -> Preferences -> Advanced -> check 'Show Develop menu in menu bar')

Under 'Develop' menu option, click on 'Empty Caches'
```

Comment: Tried, not working

Comment: Did you tried to disabled some safari add-ons ? Or are you using a download manager like Folx ?

Comment: Also tried with removing all extensions in Safari

Comment: Strange... And when safari is sucking the cpu, does it take a lot of bandwidth ?

Comment: Updated the question with network activity. It seems like no network activity at all.

Answer (score -1):

developer mode seems to be buggy; acknowledged today by Apple with recent consumer reports with the new MacBook Pro 2016.  A patch is on the way in beta testing now.